# Embedded UNIT Tests with VS CODE

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, embedded, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

So one of the guys who reports to me showed/demo'ed the C++/Testmate interface with VSCODE and GoogleTest - it's really cool and really works well. I'd like to set this up with our embedded stuff. There are many many pieces to the puzzle and I'm looking for something where I can end up with something like C++/TESTMATE + GoogleTest working in an embedded environment.  There are some challenges though.

I have LITTLE to ZERO confidence that this is even doable. I'd like to be proven wrong, and that's why I am asking questions here, I am looking for a way to make this possible work in some way.  I also think that those that do not work in the embedded world often just say "Oh its easy you just do this..." and maybe I just do not know enough about the tool to say - yea, that is actually doable. I would like to be proven wrong.

Developing or using another UNIT TEST Framework that does not integrate into the IDE is just not viable for me - Yea, I can go and write my own 100% standalone solution however my goal here is the simplicity provided by the Google Test framework and how it us useable under VS CODE.

**Simple Example**

An overly simplistic example of what I am talking about might be testing the battery management software that controls the charging of a laptop. Your test needs to control and measure the power supply, the thermal (heat) condition of the target laptop, and simulate various loads the laptop might be drawing (ie: is the laptop idle, or in use) among various other things.

Reality might also mean Various Radio simulators, temperature and vacuum chambers that run from -50C to +50C and numerous other items.

I am also generally talking about Integration tests.

**REQUIREMENT:** Remember : This is an integrated tests not a standalone unit test.

Thus, we require the ability to control other things other than the SW under test.

Typically we do this via a PYTHON SCRIPT either to a socket device or a serial port. Other times it is via a vendor supplied library that we can use to control their test equipment. EXAMPLE: https://edadocs.software.keysight.com/kkbopen/keysight-instrument-drivers-588280372.html?jmpid=zzfinddrivers

**Background**

We must test **IN HARDWARE** - we cannot use a simulated or MOCK solution - mocking business logic is easy, but often the business is dealing with other hardware and related items and that is our test goal.

Our hardware is also very fluid, we have 5 to 6 new designs a year, we create what I call "Bespoke Custom Hardware" - for our customers to develop their product/solution with.

Often what we are testing is new BSP level drivers, where (1) the hardware is very new and is not yet functional nor proven, and (2) The driver is also new - because that is the thing we are developing or customizing or integrating into this specific platform.

Often, as part of the test platform/fixture - we have external equipment the test framework needs to control.  For example - the fixture might contain an electronic load (for a power supply) - we cycle the load on and off, and meanwhile control another device to measure a frequency output. Another aspect of some (not all) tests is our power supplies are programable - we can read back the CURRENT in milli-AMPs and use that outside information as part of our overall unit test.

**QUESTION:**  Where should I start looking for this outside control script? And what about integrating this into VS CODE Unit test framework?  It seems I would be better off if I wrote the test (?harness?) in Python, but that is not what I want to debug... I want to debug Embedded C.

ie: Launch Python, but debug C... and the two need to interact with each other (See below)

**Requirement:** Test Discovery

In VS CODE there is a BEEKER icon, it lists the various tests that you can run. How would I auto populate this?

From what I have seen with google test there is a means to run the test application and have it list the available tests that are present(compiled in) - on linux this is very easy. you run the google test application(head) with --gtest-list-tests and it prints/lists the tests on standard out.

To run the equal in the embedded environment, I have an ARM ELF (Also RISCV, and MicroBlaze and other CPU) binary - I cannot run this in QEMU - sorry I do not have that hardware sufficiently emulated. What I can do is use GDB (or a command line tool) and load/flash the application onto my board, then some script (possibly python) can power cycle the device because that is required due to the chip in use.

The methods I can think of are:

a) Have a directory full of ARM ELF files - for various tests cases. The test framework would then iterate over the list of ARM ELF files -one at a time. Note: Recognize that building (N) different ELF files is an entirely additional challenge here (more below).

b) Once an ELF file is chosen, you have two options to list available tests:

B1) Load the image on the physical board (ie: flash the elf on the board), power cycle the board and run the application. The application prints the available test names out a serial port and the list of test names are captured via the test harness using  PYSERIAL.

B2) Instead: Use something like "pyelftools" - and examine the elf binary, find the symbol that is the list/table of test names and extract these directly from the ELF file - while doable, wow that is a lot of work to do.

**QUESTION:**  Which method would you suggest as a starting point?

**Requirement:** Test Selection?

VSCODE On the right hand side, under the "beeker" icon one can select a test to run.

Embedded systems do not generally have a command line. What can be done is something else.

Option(A) - create a single binary for a single test, thus if you have (N) tests you have to build (N) binaries - this seems overly complex and painfully bad... But is sometimes simpler than option (B) right below.

Option(B) - Flash the board, power cycle the board and stop/halt the application at the function MAIN(). with a breakpoint. Then using the debugger (ie: GDB command line) - poke a target variable with some number or text - inlue of parsing a command line. Then let the target resume/continue - it then uses that "poked variable" to run some type of test.

Again, capturing the result using PYTHON & PYSERIAL via the debug serial port.

**Why (N) Different ELF Files?**

On Linux you have 1GIG of ram. In a typical small embedded system (EXAMPLE: STM32F103) - I might have 256K of flash, and 48K of RAM.  I can probably dedicate 16K total code space to the unit test framework and maybe 2K of RAM space. The rest of the FLASH and RAM is set aside for my product code. I do not have another chip, and it must fit within that environment. That probably means that I can probably fit **ONE** or **TWO** tests in the binary, and not **TEN** to **TWENTY** thus to have (N) tests I may well require (N) different images to make that work.

Is this possible within the unit test framework that works with VSCODE?

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Answer (score 0):

[Testing API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/testing)

> The Testing API allows Visual Studio Code extensions to discover tests in the workspace and publish results. Users can execute tests in the Test Explorer view, from decorations, and inside commands.